# React component rendering only first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

First of all I have to say that I am new to React and that I am stuck at some point where I need some help. I am working on a web project which is basically calendar app.

The idea is simple: we have an app which displays calendar for one year in future. It is all single paged so I used react-scroll component for easier app usage.
At the sides are two menus - on the left there is a menu with months (Jan, Feb, ...) and on the right side there is a menu with days (1, 2, ..). So when user clicks on March let's say, page scrolls to that month - same goes for days.

In parent render method, I have included both menu components like this:

Parent component:

```
<MonthsMenu monthsArray={ this.state.monthsArray } onMonthActive={ this.onMonthActive.bind(this) } />

<DaysMenu month={ this.state.month } />
```

To MonthsMenu component, I pass state array which has all months and function `onMonthActive`. This is function which gets called when users scroll to certain element.

onMonthActive function in Parent:

```
onMonthActive(to) {

    var currentDate = moment(moment(to, "MMMM YYYY").unix());
    var currentDate2 = moment.unix(currentDate);

    var daysInCurrentMonth = currentDate2.daysInMonth();

    this.setState({
      month: currentDate2,
      daysInMonth: daysInCurrentMonth
    });
  }
```

This is left menu (MonthsMenu component) render:

```
render() {

    const sideMenu = this.props.monthsArray.map((month, i) => {
      var monthString = month.format("MMMM YYYY");
      var monthStringArray = monthString.split(' ');

      var currentMonth = month;

      return (
        <li key={ monthString } >
          <Scroll.Link
            activeClass="active"
            to={ monthString }
            offset={-50}
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            duration={500}
            onSetActive={this.props.onMonthActive}>
              { monthStringArray[0].substring(0, 3) }
          </Scroll.Link>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="months">
        <ul>
          { sideMenu }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So the idea is when user scrolls to certain element, notify parent with `onMonthActive` and set `month` state to current date that we scrolled. This `month` state is used later in DaysMenu (right menu) component to generate exact number of days in month.

DaysMenu component render:

```
    render() {

    var currentMonth = moment(this.props.month);
    var daysInMonth = currentMonth.daysInMonth();

    var days = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      days.push(i);
    }

    const sideMenu = days.map((day, i) => {

      var anchor = this.props.month.format("MMMM YYYY") + ' ' + day;

      return (
        <li key={ anchor } id={ anchor + ' ' + i}>
          <Scroll.Link
            activeClass="active"
            to={anchor}
            offset={-60}
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            duration={500}
            onSetActive={this.dayActive}>
              { day }
          </Scroll.Link>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="days">
        <ul>
          { sideMenu }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Scrolling by months works like it should. The problem is that scrolling by days is only working for the first shown month. If I put console.log inside parent `onMonthActive` function I can see, that it is only called when I react first month and not called anymore when scrolling further. Shouldn't this work since `setState` I am using in onMonthActive causes components to rerender and create a new DaysMenu?

Sorry for long post and I hope someone knows the solution.

**EDIT**

[Calendar.jsx](http://pastebin.com/kig1mLVD)
[MonthsMenu.jsx](http://pastebin.com/YP2N3MY4)

[DaysMenu.jsx](http://pastebin.com/UhggtJJA)

Comment: I'm not seeing `componentWillReceiveProps` on your `DayMenu` component, which means that if a parent component alters the props being sent down to `DayMenu`, it won't re-render. Meaning, you change the Month, the days won't update. Try implementing that method, as it will take in `nextProps` and you can choose to update you local props or state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: @lux Thanks for answer. I have implemented componentWillReceiveProps in DayMenu component but this method is also called only one time.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is invoked each time a parent component attempts to pass down a new set of props to a component that is in the DOM. Go ahead and create an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can debug.

Comment: @lux I have added code from all 3 files in the question above. You can find links at the end. Anything else I can do to make it easier?